# can't connect IOS device to Appium

Tags: c#, appium-ios

I'm trying to run appium-desktop with automatic server in order to instal and run my app on real device.
These are my capablities

```js
{
  "deviceName": "iPhone 6",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "platformVersion": "10.2.1",
  "app": "/Users/telaviv/Downloads/Digitel.ipa",
  "automationName": "XCUITEST",
  "udid": "1593436bc7eb0a4eedb62f640462329ff2c9ce0e"
}
```

and That's the error

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not install app: 'Command 'ios-deploy --id 1593436bc7eb0a4eedb62f640462329ff2c9ce0e --uninstall --bundle /var/folders/__/hr4vwmm54wj42_w9nrzg1dg00000gn/T/2017630-3866-nrtnwe.jvqb0529/Payload/Digitel.app' exited with code 253'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the ipa is signed with a developer account and is mapped to the phone through developer.apple.com. Only if it is registered can run tests on the phone. You need a developer account in apple for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am face this problem, exit and  restart Appium server and run again Appium script solve this problem